# Geometrical explanation for Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having problems understanding these derivatives and giving them a geometrical explanation. I get that the derivative of the area of a circle means that if the radius of a circle grows with speed 1, its length grows with speed equal to the boundary’s length.

1. $\frac{d}{dx}$ $x^2 = 2x$

Does this means that the area under the curve $x^2$ grows in the same speed as the length of $2x$ ?

2. $\frac{d}{dx}$ $x^3 =3x^2$

I don't quite understand how to say this because they are both curves but in different shape. Is the area stretched out to $x^3$ ?

And for the last two questions I have a hard time imagining it. How can we explain the geometrical shape of these?

3. $\frac{d}{dx}$ $uv = u'v + uv'$
4. $\frac{d}{dx}$ $uvw = u'vw + u'w + uvw'$

Comment: The expression $\frac{d}{dx} x^2$ refers to the slope at a given point of the function $x^2$. The geometrical intuition for the derivative of a function is its slope.

Comment: @Samasambo how about if they have 2 functions like number 3 and 4?

Comment: Think of $uv$ as a new function, not two separate functions anymore.

Comment: It seems that there is a confusion between the area of a circle vs. its circumference and the area under a curve.

Comment: You have a typo in 4. which I will leave for you to fix. And the equation y=x^2 describes a parabola, not a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometric interpretation in terms of areas is more often associated to integrals and antiderivatives.

The area under the curve $y=f(x)$ is obtained by the integral $$\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ and $C$ an arbitrary constant.

You can write this as 
$$f(x)=\frac{dF(x)}{dx},$$ meaning that if the function $F(x)$ expresses the area under some curve, this curve has the equation $y=f(x)$.

The derivative is more frequently interpreted as the *slope* of the tangents to a curve of equation $y=F(x)$.

Putting these facts together, we obtain a contrieved statement that says: the slope of the curve that represents the area under the curve of equation $y=f(x)$ is given by the function $f(x)$ itself.